# How to get text from Text Box in win32 c++ on button click?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32com

I am very new to win32 gui applications.I am trying to create simple calculator application.
In that i have designed a GUI for calculator.Now i want to get text of textbox entered by user and also want to set text on click of any button i designed from 0 to 9.

For testing purpose i wrote a code to get text from textbox and tried to display it in a messagebox. But my messagebox is showing empty message. Following is my code in WinProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HWND B[16];// these are the saperate handles to each button in the main window.
        HWND hEditA,hEditB,hEditC;//handle for text box.
        char c[16][2]={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","*","/",".","="};
        int i=0,j,x=100,y=130;
        int id[15]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
        int cnt;
        //char val[20];
        TCHAR val[30] = {0};
        int len;


        switch(msg)
        {
            case WM_PAINT:
                hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
                TextOut(hdc,10,12,"Number 1:",strlen("Number 1:")+1);
                TextOut(hdc,10,47,"Number 2:",strlen("Number 2:")+1);
                TextOut(hdc,10,87,"Result  :",strlen("Result  :")+1);
                //  TextOut(hdc,10,100,"hellow sachin",strlen("hello sachin")+1);
                EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
                break;

            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage (0);
                break;

            case WM_CREATE:

                            hEditA=CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER|ES_NUMBER|ES_RIGHT, 100, 10, 150, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                            hEditB=CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER|ES_NUMBER|ES_RIGHT, 100, 45, 150, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                            hEditC=CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER|ES_NUMBER|ES_RIGHT, 100, 85, 150, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                            cnt=0;
                            for(i=0;i<16;i++)
                            {
                                if(cnt==4)
                                {
                                    y=y+40;
                                    x=100;
                                    cnt=0;


                                }

                                if(cnt<4)
                                {
                                    B[i] =   CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT(c[i]),    
                                         WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                                         x, y, 30, 30,        
                                         hWnd, (HMENU) id[i], NULL, NULL);
                                    x=x+40;
                                    //y=y+30;
                                    cnt++;

                                }
                            }

            case WM_COMMAND:

                    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                    {
                        case 1:
                                len=GetWindowText( hEditA,val,10);
                               MessageBox(hWnd,(LPSTR)val, "Info", MB_OK); 
                                SetWindowText( hEditB,val);




                               break;
                                    }
    }
}
```

B. I also want to display the caption of the button pressed in the textbox.

So please can anyone help me to find the way to correct it.

thanx in advance..

Comment: Are those window handles defined in the scope of the window procedure, or global? If they are defined in the scope of the window procedure, they will be freed after `WM_CREATE` returns control to the Operating System.

Comment: Yes i wrote those text box handles in a WinProc method and those were not static . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the text for you:

```
SendMessage(hEditA, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)10, (LPARAM)val);
```

Are those window handles defined in the scope of the window procedure, or global? If they are defined in the scope of the window procedure, they will be forgotten after WM_CREATE returns control to the Operating System.

If they are defined in the window procedure, try:

```
static HWND hEditA, ...
```

EDIT:
You should also break from your `WM_CREATE` handler, as it will fall through to your `WM_COMMAND` handler.

Comment: No sir . .still it does not work . .still it is showing me empty msgbox. .

Comment: Yeeeehhhh . . .Thanx sir . .It worked when i made handles of these text boxes as static . . But it made to ask a question why should we declare these handles as a static ?

Comment: @Sachin Ware You define as static when they are inside a function's scope if you wish for them to keep their value the next time the function is called. You don't need to declare them as static if they are in the global scope. The reason for this is, when functions return they free up all locally defined variables, unless they are declared static.